# checking the pressed key when closing datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

When datetimepicker is used, sometimes user does not do any changes and close the datetimepicker.
After closing the datetimepicker my program checks if the date is suitable with the rest of data. I want to prevent this checking if datetimepicker is closed by escape or clicking somewhere else.

Is it possible to detect if datetimepicker is closed without choosen a date?

I use close-up property and EventArgs.

Comment: Use a `bool` variable.  Set it to *true* when you get the ValueChanged event.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you think about [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594904/5687778) approach? Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: @Dead - Validating will be raised even if the user did not pick a value.

Comment: @HansPassant It should be fired when the user attempts to change the focus to different control. OP wants to prevent the user from not picking a value.

Comment: @HansPassant :( I use close-up property. I have great touble with ValueChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the ValueChanged event fires even when the User is just browsing through the calendar. I don't see a really obvious way handle it. However the following code will do a decent job of ignoring value changes events between the DropDown and CloseUp events.

```
    bool UserIsJustLooking = false;

    private void dateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserIsJustLooking = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Tag = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserIsJustLooking)
        {
            // the user is just browsing the dates (ignore these value changed events because they aren't real)
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value changed without opening, new value is " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserIsJustLooking = false;
        if ((DateTime)dateTimePicker1.Tag == dateTimePicker1.Value)
        {
            // User did not really change the value
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User selected a new value: " + dateTimePicker1.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use close-up property not ValueChanged because I have great trouble with ValueChanged I don't know why ?

Comment: The main issue with ValueChanged is that it changes when the user has the DateTimePicker dropped down, and the user is clicking around (or moving the calendar month at a time). This produces undesirable effects if you are wanting to real-time change other controls on the form. Basically you have to ignore the ValueChanged event when the control is 'open'... which is what this code does.

Comment: I used close-up property. It fits me. Thanks very much for the answer

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that CloseUp only works if the user uses the mouse 'calendar' to select a new date.  if they change the date using the keyboard keys, no CloseUp event happens and you won't ever receive an event that the value has changed.

Comment: As you know if you click the mouse somewhere else or use the escape datetimepicker closes. I was searching a method for detecting this case for not using my checking method after closing the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in validation methods:

```
private void DateTimePicker_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //validation logic

    //if valid 
    e.Cancel = false;

    //else
    e.Cancel = true;            
}
```

Setting the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to true will prevent the control from loosing focus.

You need to attach this to your DateTimePicker **Validating** event

Answer (score 0):

After the illumination of David as I could not resolve the problem with

```
if ((DateTime)dateTimePicker1.Tag == dateTimePicker1.Value)
```

I created another version.

In public partial class I added these

```
public bool EscPressed = false;
public string calTag = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

I wrote this method

```
 private void cal_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {    
     EscPressed = false;
     if (calTag == cal.Value.ToString("d"))
          EscPressed = true;
     else
          EscPressed = false;
     cal.Visible = false;
     if (EscPressed)
        return;
     calTag = cal.Value.ToString("d");
     _textBox[1].Text = _textBox1[1].Text = calTag;
     CheckDate();
}
```

PS: Checkdate() is a method which checks if date is well chosen or not